# would you mind If I ask you that whether there is any possible way to run node.js on the base of browser

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, browser, document

Without further ado, I wonder if I can execute node.js in the level of browser.

I prefer to check the result of typescript compliation in the terminal, so I add this code in package.json.

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "tsc-watch --onSuccess \" node dist/project11.js\" "
  }
```

By using this onSuccess option, I could see the result of console.log immediately, and it was cool.

The only thing I had to do was to write "npm start" in a bash terminal shell.

**However**, the problem occurred when I wrote "document.getElementById" in typescript.

In the browser, the result was clearly seen and there was no error thankfully.

**But, in terminal**, it said 
"**ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at Object**. (C:\Users\INTEL\Desktop\web\javascript\typescript\hello\dist\project11.js:2:11)"

Because of this error, I couldn't see the other correct result from terminal.

As a novice, I searched for the method for three hours and I tried to find what is a fundamental problem and tried something like "replacing script tag in html right before body tag" or write "window.document.~~~" but they didn't work at all.

Is there any possible way to deal with "document" in node.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an npm package called [jsdom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom).

For more clarification see this [documentation](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom)

Answer (score 0):

1) server-side html generation (the simplest solution)
2) a static page which, through ajax from a javascript browser, takes a json file from the north. (the most "modern" approach)
3) communication through sockets (chats are often used)